# How to request app exit when ClickOnce is set to 'partial trust application'?

Tags: .net, clickonce

If a .NET console application is built in the VisualStudio with project settings `Security` > `Enable ClickOnce security settings` > `This is a partial trust application`, the following ways to exit application throw `SecurityException` due to insufficient privileges because they cannot access the system environment:

- `Environment.Exit()`
- `Environment.FailFast()`
- `End` statement (Visual Basic)

How to exit the application without running into this exception?

***More details:***

Exception message is: `Message=Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.`.

*This is perfectly OK*, as they obviously want to return an `ErrorLevel`, but the system environment is not accessible at that time. But do you know about any way to *prematurely* exit the application which does *not* attempt to access the environment and thus is able to exit without triggering the exception?

The only working way I found so far is to continue the execution to end of `Main()` where the application exits 'naturally'. But this sometimes adds unwanted code constructs. This is why I'm asking how to exit immediately.

*Please, in this case let's not conclude by adding privileges to the application etc. Let's keep the application restricted as it is and find a way how to exit it. Does .NET offer some other way to exit the app instantly than the above three?*

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()
```

or

```
AppDomain.Unload(AppDomain.CurrentDomain)
```

?

Comment: I've tried your suggestions:

`AppDomain.Unload(...)` throws the same `SecurityException` as shown in question and `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()` brings sort of `SecurityException` where debugger tracing stops yet before entering the method where I added this call. If you know .NET well and you doubt there are other methods of exiting, please add something like "if the above do not work, then this is probably not possible in .NET" and I'll accept the answer.